# How to fit a polynomial curve with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have to following D3 code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.error); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.error = d.error;
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.error; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Error (%)");

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
```

The data.tsv looks like this:

```
error close
100 93.24
200 -85.35
300 53.89
400 -18.57
500 198.1
600 -8.4
700 98.623
800 9.89
900 118.56
1000  98.71
```

I would like to fit a curve to these data points. Right now this code just connects the data points with straight lines. It looks like this:

[image]

I am wondering how can I fit a polynomial curve instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose interpolation function for your curve.
Look at this demo pages - 
https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ced1b9b18bd8192d2c898884033b5529
http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/c25a147970def2b02d8c7c2719dc7502

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.error); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); })
    .curve(d3.curveCardinalClosed);
```

[d3 curves documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curves).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  the line.curve([curve]).
As a parameter you pass a curve type also part of d3.
This link contains a good example:
https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/26363646c478b2028d36e7274cedefa6

And the api reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line_curve

Answer (score 1):

You could use d3 interpolate

Heres the github page: https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate

```
const i = d3.interpolateNumber(10, 20);
i(0.0); // 10
i(0.2); // 12
i(0.5); // 15
i(1.0); // 20
```